# How can I send push notification to multiple devices in one go in iPhone?

Tags: php, iphone, push-notification

I want to send same messages to all devices who are registered with application but how can send them without making multiple connections...

My current PHP code:

```
ctx = stream_context_create();  
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');  
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);  
if (!$fp)
{
  print "Failed to connect $err $errstr\n";
  return;
}
$msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
fwrite($fp, $msg);
```

Comment: Could you format your code a little better by [putting 4 whitespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) before each code line? Right now it's not readable.

Comment: I hope it's readable now... :)

Comment: @Prabh -- can you show me the final  code for how you solved this issue?  Im trying to achieve the same thing -- thanks!

Comment: Hi Tamak, it was long back so I dont have the code but I used for loop at tht time to send msg to all devices :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bottom line, you **can't**. You need to send a message to **each** token.

> Its **not** working like a email where you can have multiple recipients.

Once the connection is open you can send a bunch of messages, thats also the **preferred** way (based on Apples SDK).

from the SDK:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW2

> You should also retain connections with APNs across multiple notifications. APNs may consider connections that are rapidly and repeatedly established and torn down as a denial-of-service attack. Upon error, APNs closes the connection on which the error occurred.

Comment: new to PHP here, does it mean you create your connection once like $fp = stream_socket_client(
                      'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
                      $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

while you can `fwrite($fp, $msg);` multiple times (even 1000 times)?

Comment: Link is defunct

Answer (score 3):

You can use one connection to send multiple messages, so you don't need to open multiple connections. You can't use one message for multiple devices.

Comment: Bolhoed, Can you tell me how?

Comment: Just do multiple fwrite's on the same connection.

Comment: Hi @mixedCase doing multiple fwrites (ie 100+) didn't work for me, many of them did not get my push, is that possible? Should I do anything else If users to send push are 1000+?

Comment: Multiple writes works but if one of the devices is wrong, apple will not send any other connections, how to deal with it? ...and it doesnt terminate the connection so you dont know which one is wrong